# Редирект на другую страницу в JavaScript-виджете

Tags: javascript

Есть виджет для оплаты на сайте. Как сделать так чтобы после успешной оплаты через несколько секунд клиента перенаправило на другую страницу с результатами оплаты ?

Вот код виджета:

```
<div id="liqpay_checkout"></div>
  <script>
    window.LiqPayCheckoutCallback = function() {
      LiqPayCheckout.init({
        data: "{{ data }}",
        signature: "{{ signature }}",
        embedTo: "#liqpay_checkout",
        mode: "embed" // embed || popup,
          }).on("liqpay.callback", function(data){
        console.log(data.status);
        console.log(data);
        }).on("liqpay.ready", function(data){
          // ready
        }).on("liqpay.close", function(data){
          //kkkkk
        });
    };
  </script>
  <script src="//static.liqpay.ua/libjs/checkout.js" async></script>
```

Comment: Мб в разделе liqpay.ready использовать свойство wondow.location = "address_your_page"?

Comment: Для задержки использовать setTimeout (:

Comment: пробовал, почему то не работает.
У них на сайте такое обьяснение:

Также можно обработать событие открытия и закрытия виджета передав на функцию on события liqpay.ready и liqpay.close и соответствующие функции, которые выполняются при наступлении данного события.

Answer (score 0):

вообще при Checkout есть параметр в настройках, на какую страницу отправлять клиента

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]